# Adding a GUI to my application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, date, button

I have this library application that has a few different methods in its controller class.  One of them is called checkOut which is used to checkout library items.

I'm trying to make this happen when the "checkout" button is now pressed and am hoping that it can get all the necessary information from the txt fields I have created.

I did the following and it is just blowing up with red errors everywhere when I press "checkout" while running.  Any help is appreciated, thx!

```
if (source == checkoutButton)
    {
        /*JDialog checkout = new JDialog(checkoutContent, "Checkout", true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        checkout.setBounds(750, 300, 350, 190);
        checkout.setResizable(false);
        checkout.add(panel);
        checkout.setVisible(true);*/

        String borrowerID = userIDTxtField.getText();
        String code = itemIDField.getText();
        String date = dateField.getText();
        String copyString = code.substring(1);
        int copy=Integer.valueOf(copyString);

if (ctrl.checkBorrower(borrowerID))
            {

        boolean valid = false;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
        sdf1.setLenient(false);

                   while (!valid)
                   {

                   try
                   {
                       sdf1.parse(date);
                       catalogArea.setText(ctrl.checkOut(borrowerID, code, copy, date));
                       valid = true;

                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {
                       catalogArea.setText("Date is not valid. Please try again.");
                       continue;
                   }

                   }
            }
            else
            {
                catalogArea.setText("Sorry Invalid ID");
            }

    }
```

Comment: *"blowing up with red errors everywhere"*  That must be very pretty.  :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  If I had an SSCCE, there would be no reason to 'presume' or 'guess' - something I'm not especially good at. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
while (!valid)
{
try
{
   sdf1.parse(date);
   catalogArea.setText(ctrl.checkOut(borrowerID, code, copy, date));
   valid = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   catalogArea.setText("Date is not valid. Please try again.");
   continue;
}
}
```

This code will cause an effectively infinite loop if the date is invalid.  The GUI would most probably be blocked (if this is happening on the EDT - if not on the EDT, the GUI updates are incorrect) so the user would be prevented from changing the invalid date that is causing the loop.

---

To solve this problem, I'd look to 1st changing code not shown in the loop.  Basically, the `dateField` (presumably a `JTextField`), should be a `JSpinner`.

[image: SpinnerDemo]

See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) in the tutorial for that screen shot, working code, and further tips.

If the text field was instead a spinner, the entire validation shenanigans is made redundant.  The spinner will provide a valid (but not necessarily correct - User Intelligence API required) date.

Comment: @mKorbel  Too often I read questions that have me thinking "Why would you use a hammer when you need a screwdriver?".  This is one of those things where 'the right tool for the job' will help immensely. :)

Comment: ......... and I take GUI programing as non_accepted part of [Visual Arts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_arts)

Comment: @mKorbel  If only I could shape my frame like [The Church at Auvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Church_at_Auvers), I could be the ..Van GUIph of the 3rd millennium.  ;)

Comment: brrrrr, soooooooooo very bad example, ..... hmmmm this Van Gulph not ... known and famous throughout the life of ???, too :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Oh, Van GUIph is just an abbreviation of my full title, which is "Van Graphical User Interface 'ph'".  People sometimes look at me funny when I tell them my full name, so you can just call me 'Van GUIph'.

Comment: I look forward to the [corresponding L&F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh). :-)

Comment: wow, thx for all the tips everyone.   I'm definitely going to try out a JSpinner Andrew, thx for that!

Comment: still not working.  when I hardcode the item information into the checkOut method, it works fine and i get the message, "item checked out".  However, by using the variables I set above to get text from the txtfields, it does not work and shows errors.  I dont get it...

Comment: Time to post an SSCCE of your best effort.